# Django request.user not showing correct user in frontend

Tags: python, django, request, python-3.8, django-3.1

When user updates profile with username which is already in use ,message appear of "A user with that username already exists." but username on profile is changed to which user requested.
for example: if user with username test001 update profile with already taken username "test0012"

this will happen:

[image: error page screenshot]

Notice:username is updated with "test0012"

Code in frontend for username:

```
<h2 id="user-name" class="account-heading user__name">@{{ user.username }}</h2>
```

also going on "my posts" will redirect to posts of user "test0012".

code for profile and update:

```
@login_required
def profile(request):
    if request.method=="POST":
        u_form=UserUpdateForm(request.POST,instance=request.user)#,op_email=request.user.email)
        p_form=ProfileUpdateForm(request.POST,request.FILES,instance=request.user.profile)

        if u_form.is_valid() and p_form.is_valid():

        
            u_form.save()
            p_form.save()
            messages.success(request,f'Your Account has been updated!')
            
            #changing email on profile
            tusername=u_form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            temail=u_form.cleaned_data.get('email')
            registeruser=User.objects.get(username=tusername)
            registeruser.email=temail
            registeruser.save()
            
            return redirect('profile')
    

    else:
          u_form=UserUpdateForm(instance=request.user)
          p_form=ProfileUpdateForm(instance=request.user.profile)
```

userupdateform code:

```
class  UserUpdateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    email=forms.EmailField()
    username=forms.CharField(required=True,validators=[username_check,])

    class Meta:
        model =User
        fields =['username','email']
```

ProfileUpdateForm:

```
class ProfileUpdateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model=Profile
        fields=['image']
```

username_check:

```
def username_check(someusername):
   if someusername!=someusername.lower():
      raise forms.ValidationError("Only Lower case allowed.")
```

Comment: It seems the problem is in validators could you please add that here?

Comment: default validation of username, provided  by django is used here.

Comment: username_check is the default validator?

Comment: @NanthakumarJJ my bad, that validator only check for upper case alphabet in username edit: added validator code

Comment: So it looks like the problem not solved..

Comment: @NanthakumarJJ solved :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The model form first does it's own cleaning / validation, after which it assigns this data to the instance that you passed to it and calls that instance's `full_clean` method which is what gives you the error `A user with that username already exists`. But as you notice this is already too late as the instance is already *modified*, although this does not get saved to the database you are displaying the same instance.

The solution to this is to get a copy of the user instance from the database just to pass it to the form, so that the instance associated with the request stays unchanged and clean:

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model


UserModel = get_user_model()

@login_required
def profile(request):
    user = UserModel.objects.get(pk=request.user.pk)
    if request.method == "POST":
        u_form = UserUpdateForm(request.POST, instance=user)
        p_form = ProfileUpdateForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=user.profile)
        ...
    else:
        u_form = UserUpdateForm(instance=user)
        p_form = ProfileUpdateForm(instance=user.profile)
```

Comment: Is there any other way to update request.user?

Comment: @NanthakumarJJ doesn't this solve your issue? Do note that I have made changes in your code `user = UserModel.objects.get(pk=request.user.pk)` and `instance=user`, etc.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat does " User_Model = get_user_model()"  have any significant importance, can't we " user  from django.contrib.auth import User and us= User..objects.get(pk=request.user.pk) "

Comment: @user11528731 that would be me assuming you (or anyone with a similar problem) use the default user model from auth, but then you could have used a custom user model for which it won't work. Hence it is best to not directly import the user model and use the `get_user_model` function to get the model.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat  works great , thanks for your attention and explanation